# I want to change the port from 8080 to 3000 for my nodejs project

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am a beginner and I have developed an app service project with Node.js.

By default, my application is using port 8080, but I want it to use port 3000 instead.

I tried adding a new variable called PORT:3000 in the configuration>application settings.

I would like to switch the port from 8089 to 3000.

Switching the port from 8080 to 3000

Comment: you mentioned you set the variable, give it a restart once

Comment: Just to highlight, yes, Port 8080 is the default exposed port for the Node Blessed Image.
If you are leveraging App Service custom container, App Service has no control about which port your container listens on. In this case, you need to set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting to the port number, and App Service forwards requests to that port in the container. 

So, if you’re running a App Service Linux custom container, then use WEBSITES_PORT.

Comment: Assuming the application is listening for the PORT environment variable. If you're hardcoding the value and make this change, your container will likely time out on startup due to the port value mismatch. Please check this - https://azureossd.github.io/2023/02/15/Whats-the-difference-between-PORT-and-WEBSITES_PORT/index.html

Ref: https://azureossd.github.io/2022/10/17/troubleshooting-common-iisnode-issues/index.html#troubleshooting-common-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Setting the PORT variable first

Azure Portal > Configuration > Application settings > Add a new application setting
PORT = 3000

```html
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;  
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

retstart after this.

Comment: I did this already will check and get back

Comment: This is working now after going through few videos

Answer (score 0):

**If you want change the port number from 8080 to 3000.**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000; // Change this line to set the port to 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

- Go to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/).
- Navigate to your Web App Service.
- In the left sidebar, under "Settings," select "Configuration."
- In the "Application settings" section, add a new setting with the key PORT and the value 3000 (or your desired port number).
- Save the changes.

Comment: This didn't work